# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Screen'

Tags: python, attributes, screen

I'm trying to make a square with python.
Here's the code:

```
import turtle

def draw_square():

    window = turtle.Screen()
    window.bgcolor("red")

    brad = turtle.Turtle()
    brad.shape("turtle")
    brad.color("yellow")
    brad.speed(2)

    brad.forward(100)
    brad.right(90)
    brad.forward(100)
    brad.right(90)
    brad.forward(100)
    brad.right(90)
    brad.forward(100)
    brad.right(90)


    window.exitonclick()
draw_square()
```

But I get this error:

```
File "C:/Python27\turtle.py", line 4, in draw_square
  window = turtle.Screen()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Screen'
```

Comment: You named your file `turtle.py` Rename it to something else and try again.  If you also have `turtle.pyc`, remove that too.

Answer (score 4):

you called your file `turtle.py` so you end up importing your own file instead of the module, rename it and remove the `.pyc` files (possibly in a `__pycache__` folder) and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks! But how do I rename the file?

Besides .py, there is .txt.
I tried it, but it still doesn't work

Comment: @andrei: Your script's extension should be `.py`. May I suggest  `turtle_square.py` for a file name?

Comment: Got it brother! :)

Thank you so much. Apparently I had to delete all the other files that were saved so far for this project. And then I renamed it to my_turtle.